# dependency injection web api .net 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6

Начал писать web api на .net 6 , нашел у индусика видео как сделать класс Startup в .net 6, переписал всё хорошо работало, попытался добавить .AddScoped и вылетает exception, что где не так написал?

```
public static class Startup
{
    public static WebApplication InitializeApp(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        ConfigureServices(builder);
        var app = builder.Build();
        Configure(app);

        return app;
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddControllers();

        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IParkingService, ParkingService>();
    }

    private static void Configure(WebApplication app)
    {
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Program :

```
var app = Startup.InitializeApp(args);
app.Run();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ParkingService` покажете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ зашел в ParkingService и увидел что конструктор принимает параметры, создал пустой конструктор и заработало, спасибо что в нужном направлении направили)

Comment: Вам про это ошибка говорила (в самом конце `ParkingService: Unable to resolve service ...`, скорей всего писала какой сервис найти не могла), я лишь хотел в этом убедиться. Так что, читайте внимательно то, что пишется в ошибках.